# How to include recent security patch (APFS plain password vulnerability) into already downloaded macOS High Sierra installer image?

Tags: macos, software-update, high-sierra

Several hours ago Apple released a fix update for macOS that solves the issue with "Vulnerability Exposes Password of Encrypted APFS Volumes in Plain Text".

My question is:

Straight when High Sierra became available I pulled the Installer (last icon in the bottom right corner).

I **assume** that this files **does NOT** have recent patch included since it was downloaded before the fix was created / released. Now pretend that I will make a bootable USB flash drive and install this version of High Sierra in another MacBook. To get the fix I will pave to go to App Store and search for updates but what if (in theory) I won't have internet connection on that Mac?

Exact question:
**How to always get installer with recent fixes? Should I remove that file from `/Applications` and re-download it each time new minor version (`10.13.X`) will be released?**

*On my main Mac I noticed that High Sierra is versioned as `10.13` but after installing the update the version stayed unchanged. It's not `10.13.1`.*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can't merge an update into an older macOS installer app easily. So you have to re-download the full installer to get the most current version. Check that you don't get the restricted (20 MB) installer only app.

After downloading the first full installer (without installing it), move it to a folder and create a dmg choosing the folder (or alternatively zip the app).

Then install the upgrade or trash the macOS installer.app.

After Apple announces and publishes a new installer (not necessarily as a point release update), download it again. Repeat the steps above. If you don't need the old installer.dmg anymore, trash it. I usually keep them.

---

Under certain circumstances (often after moving the macOS installer.app to an arbitrary folder) downloading the new release will replace the old macOS installer in-place.

---

To check the build version grep the the file /Contents/Info.plist for *DTSDKBuild*:

```
grep DTSDKBuild -A1 .../Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

The golden master's build version was *17A362a*.

The first installer's build version available to the public was *17A364*.

The latest build version as of today is *17A400* (small installer) or *17A403* (large installer).